# How to fitch the result from Yii active recorde query with relations and scopes

Tags: yii, yii-relations

This is my code

```
$vacanciesObjects = Vacancies::model()->status('approved')->visibility('Visible')->removed(0)->archived(0)->findAll(
array(
    'with'=>array(
        'job'=>array(
            //'select' => 'title',
            'scopes'=>array(
                'offline'  => array(0),
            ),
            'with' => array(
                'employer'=>array(
                    'scopes'=>array(
                        'status_id_not_in'  => array('Blocked'),
                    ),
                ), 
            ),
        ),
    ), 'limit'=> 5, 'condition' => 'number_of_views > 0', 'order' => 'number_of_views DESC',
    )
);
```

I can get the values for the columns in table vacancies but not from other table, any help regarding this ?

sorry I'm newbie on Yii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out this problem by this

```
$vacanciesObject->job['title']
```